# Independence of components in PCA

Tags: pca, factor-rotation, orthogonal

Let's have spatio-temporal dataset ($Y \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times T}$). Where $L$ stands for spatial grid points and $T$ for time. Now let's say that the noise of the system follows a multivatiate gaussian distribution. $y^\ell_t = \epsilon^\ell_t$, where $\epsilon^\ell_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$. Standing $\Sigma$ for a the covariance matrix $L \times L$.

Now, we have three different blocs (close spatial points) where the spatial points of each bloc covary together, but independently of the others bloc. Then, our $\Sigma$ is a diagonal block matrix.  For example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

Sigma = np.zeros((8*30,30*8))
Sigma[:40, :40] = 0.3  # First bloc
Sigma[88:136, 88:136] = 0.3  # Second block
Sigma[200:, 200:] = 0.3
np.fill_diagonal(Sigma,1)
plt.imshow(Sigma)
```

[[image: Correlation matrix between every grid point <span class=]$\ell$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmA5x.png)

Now we create a random data from that $\Sigma$ covariance matrix. And perform pca on top of it. I would expect the first three components to stand for each region where noise covary. For the shake of interpretability, we will assume that our spatio-temporal model lives in a $8 \times 30$ space, that is $L = 240$. In this spatio temporal model there are three blocs of covariant points corresponding to the contiguous grid-points 0:44, 88:136 and 200:240. According to $\Sigma$. Then,

```
Y = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(8*30), Sigma, size=50000)
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(Y)
for i in range(3):
    # Reshaping the components to a spatial representation allows us to plot
    # the components as the contribution of each grid point to each component. 
    # The spatial dimensions are 30 x 8.
    plt.imshow(pca.components_[i, :].reshape((30,8)))  
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

[image: 1st PC]
[image: 2nd PC]
[image: 3rd PC]

The fact is, that I see that they are correlated. And I'm not really sure why, given that I would expect that the principal components of PCA to be orthogonal between them. I also plot the correlation matrix of the first three components.

```
components = pca.components_
corr_2 = np.corrcoef(components)
plt.imshow(corr_2)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Covariance matrix of first 3 PCs]

Shouldn't the elements outside of the diagonal of that matrix be 0?

I've also try Varimax rotation, where the three components are now independent.

[image: 1st PC rotated with Varimax]
[image: 2nd PC rotated with Varimax]
[image: 3rd PC rotated with Varimax]

I guess I am missing some fundamental understanding of what means that the components are orthogonal. Could someone bring light on why the correlation matrix of the 3 comnponents has non-zeros outside of the diagonal?

Comment: your expectations of PCA component vectors are wrong. why are you even grouping 30x8? nothing in your code suggests there needs to be any kind of grouping by 8 or 30

Comment: I edit it, hoping that now is more clear. At the very end, my question is: shouldn't be the components independent?

Comment: the components are independent. it's your interpretation of independence that is puzzling. what is this about '.reshape((30,8))'?

Comment: "The components are independent". If that is the case, why are non-zero elements outside of the diagonal in the correlation matrix between the first three components? I mean, sure I am wrong, but I don't understand why the correlation matrix of the components is not showing non-correlation between the components. Because in my intuition of PCA the components must be orthogonal.

Comment: Components are orthogonal